# VPS as dynamic DNS

Tags: networking, routing, vps

I have a domain to which I have access to the DNS administration, but my registrar does not have an API.

I have a VPS that I host my own websites.

I have a home fibre connection that sometimes changes IP and my home (Raspberry Pi) VPN becomes impossible to connect to as I do not know the new public IP.

As a workaround I have set up PushBullet (along with a script that runs daily) to send the new public IP to my phone, so i can update my VPN client and be able to access my home VPN. All works well.

I'm getting pretty annoyed with the frequency at which my IP changes and I have to keep editing and re-importing the VPN profile on my phone. I twon't let me change the IP without re-importing. Not the end of the world, but not the point.

As I have my own domain and VPS I was wondering how I could go about utilising my existing assets to create, essentially, a DIY DNS server or "forwarder" so I can create a subdomain to use in my config files, but also write a script on my Raspberry Pi to automatically update my VPS with the new IP so that any request (OpenVPN traffic) is sent to my Rasperry Pi server?

I *could* join up DynDNS or A-N-Other dynamic DNS provider, but I think I have the right tools.

I'm not looking at changing my name servers or anything like that.... my domains and websites all work perfectly as they are...

Would this be a job for BIND? Could IPTables suffice, given it can be defined to specific traffic?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found a way to do this with bind only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create your own DNS server using BIND to take care of this issue, but in my opinion it would be best left to a dynamic DNS provider as any changes in your IP would likely be propagated in the DNS much quicker, not to mention security concerns associated with a diy DNS server can be complicated.
I personally run a server computer on my not fiber home internet behind a router running dd-wrt firmware. I utilize afraiddns.org which dd-wrt has a configuration specifically for dynDNS. It has never had a problem and works like a charm.

Comment: I ultimately went with NO-IP and created a CNAME from my own domain to the NO-IP free domain. I then use pfSense (my router) to update the account. I just get the emails from NO-IP asking to renew the free domain. Not such a big problem. Your advice about DIY DNS is quite right and, ultimately, I found something that is quite easy to manage and requires minimal maintenance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic DNS with Docker, Go and Bind9

https://github.com/dprandzioch/docker-ddns allows you to set up a dynamic DNS server that allows you to connect to devices at home from anywhere in the world. All you need is a cheap VPS, a domain and access to it's nameserver.